# socket.io client-java latency on android client responding to server request

Tags: android, websocket, socket.io

I am sending an echo request from a node.js server to an android client and it takes 50ms to 150ms for the android client to receive the message. When I initiate a echo request from the android client to the server I can get a round trip emit and ack in under 6ms consistently. The same setup using angular on chrome browser responds to the server in under 3ms. Is there some configuration setting in this library that would decrease the latency to messages sent to the android client or is this something inherit to the protocol on android devices? I've tried two different android devices running 4.4.4 and 5.1.1. The following is the code running in my android activity.

```
   mSocket = IO.socket(Routes.SocketController);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
    }

    mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            Log.d(TAG, "event connect");
        }
    });

    mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            Log.d(TAG, "event disconnect");
        }
    });

// respond to request from server with client current time
    mSocket.on(Const.Ping,new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            Date now = new Date();
            mSocket.emit(Const.Pong, now.getTime());
        }
    });
```

I'm using node.js v5.4.1
socket.io.client-java 0.6.3
android 5.1.1 on Nexus 4

Tried again using koush AndroidAsync library and still getting poor performance

```
public class AndroidAsyncWebSockets {
private static final String TAG = AndroidAsyncWebSockets.class.getSimpleName();

private WebSocket mSocket;

public AndroidAsyncWebSockets() {
    Log.d(TAG, "AndroidAsync object created");
    connectWebSocket();
}

private void connectWebSocket() {
    URI uri;
    Routes routes = new Routes("test");
    String server = routes.webSocketController();

    try {
        uri = new URI(server);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "connecting to " + uri.toString());

    AsyncHttpClient.WebSocketConnectCallback mWebSocketConnectCallback = new AsyncHttpClient.WebSocketConnectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception ex, WebSocket webSocket) {
            if (ex != null) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            mSocket = webSocket;

            webSocket.setStringCallback(new WebSocket.StringCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onStringAvailable(String s) {
                    processCommand(s);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    AsyncHttpClient mAsyncHttpClient = AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance();
    mAsyncHttpClient.websocket(uri.toASCIIString(), null, mWebSocketConnectCallback);
}

public void processCommand(String message) {
    String cmd="";
    String data="";

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(message);
        cmd = jsonObject.getString("cmd");
        data = jsonObject.getString("data");
    }
    catch(JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onmessage " + e.toString());
    }

    switch (cmd) {
        case "Ping" :
            //Log.d(TAG, "Ping " + data);
            sendPong();
            break;
    }
}

public void sendPong() {
    Date now = new Date();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("cmd", Const.Pong);
        jsonObject.put("data", now.getTime());

        sendMessage(jsonObject.toString());
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "sendPong " + e.toString());

    }
}

public void sendMessage(String text) {
    mSocket.send(text);
}
```

}

Comment: did you solve this issue? we have the same problem!

Comment: This seems to be an android issue.  I have tried using plain tcp sockets and have similar results.  I'm guessing that this has to do with the way android does multi-threading.  I have tried increasing the priority of the background thread and that doesn't help.

Comment: thanks for answering. we are going  to try with plain websockets. and see.

Comment: tried websockets as well with same results.

Comment: hey, we have just finished moving al to websocket. i must tell you performance improved 3,4 times. it took around 80-100ms with socketio. it  now takes 20-30ms. we used a lib called android async (it uses native OS io, not threads). it worked perfectly for us.

Comment: would you mind posting some sample code for your implementation?